# Get the cancelling rate of a vendor ignoring a certain state, in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Let's say I have a table representing sales with these attributes:

- a `state` that can be `sold`, `waiting`, `unknown` or `cancelled`
- a `vendor`
- a `buyer`
- a `cancellor` that is either the `vendor` or the `buyer` in case the sale's `state` is `cancelled`, and `null` for other states.

I want to compute the cancelling rate for *Joe*. Right now I'm doing two SQL requests. The first one gets the number of cancelled sales by *Joe*:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n_cancelled FROM sales WHERE cancellor = "Joe"
```

The second one gets the number of sales where *Joe* was involved, excluding the ones whose `state` is `unknown` or `waiting`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n_sales FROM sales
WHERE
  STATE in ("sold", "cancelled")
  AND (vendor = "Joe" OR buyer = "Joe")
```

I then compute my cancelling rate by dividing the results of these two requests.

I'm interested in doing so in one request that would output the cancelling rate and also the number of sales used to compute it (`n_sales` here). How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(cancellor = 'Joe') as n_cancelled,
       SUM(state in ('sold', 'cancelled') AND 'Joe' IN (vendor, buyer)) AS n_sales
FROM sales
WHERE ( (cancellor = 'Joe') or
        (state in ('sold', 'cancelled') AND 'Joe' IN (vendor, buyer))
      );
```

You can do the division in the query as well.

Note:  This keeps the `WHERE` clause, which is not strictly necessary.  But reducing the number of rows before aggregating the data can improve performance.

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for. You mention that it is possible to do the division within the query, can you explain how? The only way I found is: `SELECT SUM(cancellor = 'Joe') as n_cancelled, SUM(state in ('sold', 'cancelled') AND 'Joe' IN (vendor, buyer)) AS n_sales, SUM(cancellor = 'Joe')/SUM(state in ('sold', 'cancelled') AND 'Joe' IN (vendor, buyer)) (...)`, but I'm certain you had something better in mind.

Comment: @nicoco . . . That's pretty much what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

To do it all in one query:

```
SELECT 
    ( SELECT ... ) /   -- How many cancelled (as already formulated)
    ( SELECT ... );    -- Total number (as already formulated)
```